# 3 дива в строке. в 1 и 3 - содержимое. средний должен заполнять остаток по ширине

Tags: css, вёрстка, html

Собственно мне нужно чтобы видимые строки были на всю ширину экрана и при этом чтоб многоточий было потребное количество. Ожидаемо нужно в классе dot поставить 100% ширину но тогда этот средний див вытеснит из строки остальные и получится фигня.

```css
.des
{
 border: 0px solid #A5A39B;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: auto;
}
.dot
{
 border: 0px solid #A5A39B;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
 width: 200px;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class=des>ололо</div><div class=dot></div><div class=des>пыщьпыщьпыщь</div><br>
<div class=des>ололо</div><div class=dot></div><div class=des>пыщьпыщь</div><br> 
<div class=des>ололо</div><div class=dot></div><div class=des>9нлнглнлнглн</div><br>
```

Comment: Собственно мне нужно чтобы видимые строки были на всю ширину экрана и при этом чтоб многоточий было потребное количество. Ожидаемо нужно в классе  dot поставить 100% ширину но тогда этот средний див вытеснит из строки остальные и получится фигня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С `flexbox` нет ничего легче. Только вот [поддержка браузеров](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) - с 11 IE.

```css
.row{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.des
{
 border: 0px solid #A5A39B;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: auto;
}
.dot
{
 border: 0px solid #A5A39B;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
 overflow: auto;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -moz-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class=des>ывв</div><div class=dot></div><div class=des>ывываваыва</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class=des>ываывава</div><div class=dot></div><div class=des>ыававыавыаававыавыа</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class=des>ывавыаваывыа</div><div class=dot></div><div class=des>ывавыыа</div>
</div>
```

Более сложный, извращенный и костыльный, но зато **кроссбраузерный** вариант:

```css
.row {
    position: relative;
}
.des {
 background-color: white;     
    display: inline-block;   
}
.des.left{
    padding-right: 4px;
}
.des.right{
    padding-left: 4px;
    float: right;
}
.dot {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 13px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="des left">ывв</div><div class=dot></div><div class="des right">ывываваыва</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="des left">ываывава</div><div class=dot></div><div class="des right">ыававыавыаававыавыа</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="des left">ывавыаваывыа</div><div class=dot></div><div class="des right">ывавыыа</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Comment: @Alexey если ответ вам помог - пожалуйста, отметьте его как верный, поставив галочку слева от ответа.